# Where is MATLAB setpath file?

Tags: matlab, configuration, environment-variables

I would like to export and change the folder of setpath file from MATLAB. But I don't where this file is.

Comment: On Mac OS, it's in /Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/toolbox/local/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, it's `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m` in which you need to replace the `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a` part with your install directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks, though I use Window XP, but the 'pathdef.m' is still the same as you described.

Comment: or simply call: `which pathdef`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of exporting/modifying the `pathdef` file directly, you can do:

```
str = path;
save myPathBackup.mat str
```

When you want to restore it, do:

```
load myPathBackup.mat
path(str)
```